# Better way for authentication in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I know two way for authentication:
first: using `FormsAuthentication`:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, login.RememberMe);
```

and the other way : using `FormsAuthenticationTicket`

```
  var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Email.ToString(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300000), login.RememberMe, "a");
                var ticketEncrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                var cookie = new HttpCookie("eshop", ticketEncrypted);
                if (login.RememberMe)
                {
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(100);
                }
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

i want to know which one is better? and when i should use first one and when the other way?

Comment: suggest changing the title of your post to something that better reflects what you're asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method also uses `FormsAuthenticationTicket` - follow the source code to `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie` and you can see

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthenticationTicket.FromUtc(2, userName, utcNow, expirationUtc, createPersistentCookie, string.Empty, strCookiePath);
string str = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket, hexEncodedTicket);
```

i.e. starting to look similar to your second code sample

Unless you are using [cookieless auth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx) then both are doing effectively the same thing i.e. **setting a cookie in the browser**

You might use the latter if you wanted finer control over what attributes the cookie has.

Comment: are you mean both ways are same, and first way just encapsulate second way?

Comment: what i'm saying is that under certain conditions they will lead to the same result. the former has the ability to do cookieless which is entirely different to using cookies but assuming you DO use cookies (which most do) then yes the former encapsulates the latter (maybe not exactly as you wrote in your sample but it has the potential)